# How to "Show Only This Frame" - jQuery/javascript solution needed

Tags: javascript, html, html-frames

In FF we can right-click "Show This Frame Only". So how to do it in javascript/jquery? Becoz i want to remove my webapps banner (which inside another frame of another frameset) but fail.

Comment: Reviewing back my 5 years back question, it really sounds silly. With lack of knowledge, the question itself would be lame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i could understand, you want to remove your web-page's head banner. That is, your page is inside an iframe and you want that it automatically take over the parent page as soon as it loads. To do that, add this javascript code:

```
top.document.location.href="your_page_link";
```